As there any indication that cats, given the choice, prefer to avoid inbreeding?
There are many species where males are expelled from their mother's group (orca and dolphin, same with lions) after they reach the age at which they can breed probably. There are also species where a female shows interest in a newcomer over members of her natal group (perhaps males also feel this way). Both of these behaviors would tend to reduce inbreeding.
I also know that both cats and dogs will mate with siblings, even with parents (I think). But my question is, is there at least a tendency to gravitate towards non-relatives when non-relatives are available for mating?
(This is not to suggest that they even know what a sibling is, although perhaps a cat might; but just some aversion to inbreeding based perhaps on scent but in cats clearly it is not a very pronounced aversion.)

in the wild cats chase away the young males,it is natures way to reduce the risk of inbreeding.

Anecdotal observation: cat mothers become aggressive towards their offspring (male and female) once they reach puberty. This includes loud hissing, growling and swatting at the kittens if they come too close. In nature this would result in the offspring wandering off to find their own territory, but it's no security against inbreeding. There's also the widely accepted theory that mammals (including humans) can detect how compatible a mate is based on their personal scent, but only to a limited degree. If given the choice, a cat should chose an unrelated mate, but that's still no guarantee.
